# How to avoid intermittent empty lines when using FileOutputStream with append = false?

Tags: java, java-io

The following code sometimes leaves the `random.txt` file with no content:

```
final Random rand = new Random();

while (true) {
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("random.txt", false);
         PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fos, true)) {
        pw.println(rand.nextLong());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This can be verified using `tail`:

```
$ tail -f random.txt
511109499422519327

-4120669548002912852
-6691981558077108749
-3630360891256027458
2917713483009724854
-5999569794311404435
-7616466037397807657
6997723694593334477
-7350203015863330163
1355067773463270538
-8140835511024500423
-2536681669468724500
-2926317178660145957
-6983787629710676243
7119127016459332336

7186294589323134873
-8389505833590104437
197327637272321424
-1458700265861408851
5685819798785563231
4060059342974359248
215297222019419003
2913123181036087590
-5940005294121482941
5658270253202816998
```

As you can see, there are two gaps in `tail`'s output. This happens because `FileOutputStream(fileName, false)` first truncates the file, and then writes new data to it.

So if `tail` happens to be reading the content of the file right when it is truncated, it shows an empty line.

Other than using techniques that involve multiple files, etc. is there a way to make sure the *truncation and write* operations happen atomically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Other than using techniques that involve multiple files, etc. is there a way to make sure the truncation and write operations happen atomically?

No.  At the base level, the truncation and file write are two separate syscalls, and the OS does not provide a way to combine two syscalls into an atomic operation (or transaction).

If your intention is to find an edge-case for `tail -f` then you have succeeded.  Otherwise, there are probably better / more efficient ways to do what you are trying to do here .... like writing to a pipe, or appending to a file.  And if there is some particular reason why you need to do this, consider filtering out the blank lines.

Actually, I am concerned that there could be a worse problem here than occasional blank lines.  It is possible that you are also *losing non-blank lines* if the Java program truncates the file before `tail` has read the last line.  (Try replacing `rand.nextLong()` with the value of an incrementing counter ... and see if you see all of the numbers in the `tail` output.)

Comment: I just used `tail` to show that this problem could happen. My actual use case is not related to `tail` at all. The problem I am trying to solve is to make sure when the Java app crashes, the text file is not in an empty state. There are other ways that I can solve the problem (e.g. by not storing the data into a file and instead using a DB – embedded or otherwise), but I was just curious to see if Java has any built-in tools to achieve this. Using `RandomAccessFile`, in some special scenarios I can achieve my goal (e.g. knowing that all numbers have the same length) but that's another story.

Comment: In short.  It is not possible.

Comment: The best you can do with files is to do something with file renaming, but even that is non-atomic ...